# The variable 'control' is either undeclared or was never assigned - Except it is, and the application compiles

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2017, designer

My designer view started to throw up this error today. However, the application compiles without error and the controls are useable.

The custom control is defined in the designer correctly. If i click "ignore and continue" the designer loads up fine, but the control mentioned is missing.

So far I have tried:

Cleaning, rebuilding then restarting visual studio hasn't worked.

I haven't made any changes since using it yesterday, then walking into the office today.

My constructors are

```
public CalendarWindow(MainWindow owner)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this._owner = owner;
}

public CalendarWindow(int job, int visit, DataTable customer, DataTable address)
{

    InitializeComponent();

    this.addressDetails = address;
    this.customerDetails = customer;
    this.visitID = visit;
    jobID = job;
}
```

and inside `InitializeComponent()` in designer.cs the controls are declared

```
// 
// panel1
// 
this.panel1.Anchor = ((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles)((((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Top | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Bottom) 
| System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Left) 
| System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Right)));
this.panel1.AutoScroll = true;
this.panel1.Controls.Add(this.label5);
this.panel1.Controls.Add(this.label4);
this.panel1.Controls.Add(this.calendar4); \\designer "error" points to here
this.panel1.Controls.Add(this.label3);
this.panel1.Controls.Add(this.calendar3); \\designer "error" points to here
this.panel1.Controls.Add(this.calendar2); \\designer "error" points to here    
this.panel1.Controls.Add(this.calendar1); \\designer "error" points to here
this.panel1.Controls.Add(this.label2);
this.panel1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(218, 12);
this.panel1.Name = "panel1";
this.panel1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(873, 628);
this.panel1.TabIndex = 10;
this.panel1.MouseDown += new 
System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler(this.calendar1_MouseDown);
```

[image]

Comment: Show the code where you get the error, without any we can only guess

Comment: @EpicKip there is no code to show. Its a design view issue that appears quite common, however none of the solutions on here so far have worked

Comment: You say it gives an error, usually this error points to a location. And also, we can't help you if we can't even come close to reproducing

Comment: @EpicKip The error points to a line of code that isn't in error. Its a fault within the IDE itself, the code is fine otherwise it wouldn't compile and work.

Comment: The fact that the custom control is gone means there is something wrong :) and also if this is an IDE error how can one reproduce this to help you?

Comment: @EpicKip i didn't expect someone to reproduce it. What im looking for is potential solutions to the problem. I;ve updated the question with some code, but its not the code thats the issue. As such, im hoping someone else who has experienced the issue might be able to weigh in. The fact that it compiles correctly, and the controls work perfectly when its running proves that something else is happening in the IDE

Comment: @EpicKip Also note, that it was fine yesterday, and suddenly stopped today when no changes were made (as stated in the question)

Comment: I'm not saying its your fault, I'm just trying to make people (and me) able to help you more :). I take it you can confirm the calendar4 is being made in the designer file?

Comment: @EpicKip if it wasn't then it wouldn't be in the running program.

Comment: `but the control mentioned is missing`? Which one? :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141653/discussion-between-epickip-and-takarii).

Comment: @EpicKip "If i click "ignore and continue" the designer loads up fine, but the control mentioned is missing." - in the design view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like I've managed to solve this problem.

While the compiler didn't have any problems compiling the code and running the application, it didn't like some code within the control itself.

I only managed to catch this because i attempted to add the same control to the form after hitting "ignore and continue" at which point it refused to add it and provided me with direction to what was causing the problem, which happened to be in a class that wasn't part of the control but was used by it.

Correcting that error solved the problem.

I'm no wiser as to why it would compile and run without problems, yet the errors fed back made no reference to the offending artifact.

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same problem and I fixed it. Actually Visual Studio only works with X86 controls and you can't create a user control in X64 mode and use it.

You should add a new class library in Any CPU mode and build the library. then you can add its DLL in your project and it works.

If it doesn't you must go to the Configuration manager and set the "Active solution platform" to X64 also do that for all subprojects.
remember that build option has to be checked.
and go to the properties of the class library and click on the build tab. then set the "platform target" to Any CPU.